# passport.js Login Not Working

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, passport.js

I am using mongodb and mongoose as my database, i am able to register users but once registered can't login .As I click login, it keep on loading and never stops. I searched the internet for an answer but couldn't find it. Hoping for a positive reply.

I am trying to figure it out, but I had no success.

Here is the code:

**auth.js(contains login function)**

```
router.route('/login')
     .get((req, res, next)=>{
     let context = {}
     res.render('login', context)
})
     .post(passport.authenticate('local',{
      successRedirect: '/',
      failureRedirect:'/login'
}));
```

**users.js(database file)(i am using mongodb)**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const crypto = require('crypto');

let userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email:{
        type:String,
        unique:true,
        required:true,
    },
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true,
    },
    hash:String,
    salt:String,
    facebookId:String
});

userSchema.methods.setPassword = function (password){
    this.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
    this.hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'sha1').toString('hex');
}


userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password){
    let hash = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(password, this.salt, 1000, 64, 'sha1').toString('hex');
    return this.hash === hash;
}

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

**passport.js**

```
const passport = require('passport');
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

passport.serializeUser(function(user, done){
    done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done){
    User.findById(id, function(err, user){
        done(err, user);
    });
});

passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField:'email'
},
function(username, password, done){
    User.findOne({email:username, function(err, user){
        if(err) return done(err);
        if(!user){
            return done(null, false,{
                message:'incorrect username and password'
            });
        }
        if(!user.validPassword(password)){
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'incorrect username and password'
            });
        }
        return done(null, user);
    }});
}

));
```

**register.hbs(Html file)**

```
<h3>New Account</h3>
<div class="mdl-grid center">
    <form method="post" class="registerForm">
        {{#each errorMessages}}
        <div class="dialog mdl-cell mdl-cell--3-offset-desktop mdl-cell--1-offset-tablet mdl-cell--6-col">
            {{this.msg}}
        </div>
        {{/each}}
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="name" name='name' value="{{ name }}">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="name">First Name</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="email" id="email" name='email' value="{{ email }}">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="email">Email</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="pass" name='password' value="{{ password }}">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="password">Password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col">
            <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="password" id="c_pass" name='c_pass' value="{{ c_pass }}">
            <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="c_pass">Confirm Password</label>
        </div>
        <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col" type="submit">
            Register
        </button>

        <div>or</div>

        <a class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-button--colored mdl-cell mdl-cell--6-col" href='/auth/facebook'>
            Sign In with Facebook
        </a>

    </form>
</div>
```

**app.js(main file)**

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const expressValidator = require('express-validator');

const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const passport = require('passport');
const session = require('express-session');

require('./passport');
const config = require('./config');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var authRouter = require('./routes/auth');


mongoose.connect(config.databaseConn, { useNewUrlParser: true });
global.User = require('./models/user.js');

var app = express();
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(expressValidator());
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(session({
  secret:config.sessionKey,
  resave:false,
  saveUninitialized:true,
  cookie:{secure:true}
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use((req, res,next)=>{
  if(req.isAuthenticated()){
    res.locals.user =req.user;
  }
  next();
});

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/', authRouter);
```

This is not the complete code. Please refer the link below for complete code.
https://github.com/satyamdhawan/collaborative_editor

Please review the complete code on GitHub.

Comment: Could you please include *all* the code that you think might be relevant in the question details? It will be easier for others to find

Comment: Thank you @crizzis for pointing out, i will post all the details regarding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you check if changing this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField:'email'
},
function(username, password, done){
    User.findOne({email:username, function(err, user){
        if(err) return done(err);
        if(!user){
            return done(null, false,{
                message:'incorrect username and password'
            });
        }
        if(!user.validPassword(password)){
            return done(null, false, {
                message: 'incorrect username and password'
            });
        }
        return done(null, user);
    }});
}
```

to this:

```
passport.use(
    'local',
    new LocalStrategy(
        {usernameField: 'email'},
        (email, password, done) => {
            User.findOne({where: {email: email}})
                .then(user => {
                    if(!user){
                        return done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username and password. '});
                    }

                    return user.validPassword(password) ?
                        done(null, user) :
                        done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username and password. '});
                })
                .catch(() => done(null, false, {message: 'Incorrect username and password. '}))
        }
    )
)
```

makes a diference

Comment: It solves the problem but why are you including "where" in the code, "where" keyword is causing problems. I really dont know why but i am egar to know. If anyone has an answer? @Svetoslav Petrov

Comment: Hopefully this will help you http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage#complex-filtering-or-not-queries